# Segmentation fault error when compiler with one gcc compiler but not with other gcc compilers

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am running into a segmentation fault error in my code and I am not sure what may be causing it.  What is even more odd is that when I run I compile/run in gcc-4.4.6 RH6 I obtain no error, but on other compilers/linux distros I get a segmentation fault error.

Here is a snippet of the part of the code that I think may be generating the issue:

```
int BIN_SIZE=(2*width)/bins;
//binCounts and binCounts2 store the fragment counts in each bin. mask=1 flags histone modification site

float **binVals;

binVals = (float **)malloc(chromNum*sizeof(int *));
//Initialize the arrays
totalBinNum = 0;

for (i=0;i<chromNum;i++)
{
    totalBinNum += chromInfo[i].chromSize/BIN_SIZE+1;
    binVals[i] = (float *)malloc((chromInfo[i].chromSize/BIN_SIZE+1)*sizeof(float));
    memset(binVals[i], 0, (chromInfo[i].chromSize/BIN_SIZE+1)*sizeof(float));
}
```

If you know some easy catch on what may be causing the error please let me know?  Otherwise it could also be in some other part of the code leading to not a smart Q :(

Comment: **[Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)**

Comment: `malloc(chromNum*sizeof(int *));` I fail to see the `int*` here.

Comment: Which other compiler versions?  Newer or older than GCC 4.4.6?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but on Linux it's easy to compile with debug info ('-g'), run your program with GDB, and use the "backtrace" command (if needed).  I'd try that, because it's a lot easier to figure out what you did wrong if you know what line the error occurs on. :)

Comment: have you tried valgrind?

Comment: So far I tried gcc-4.4.4, gcc-4.5.3 and gcc-4.7.0 (all failed)

Comment: Not that I don't trust your code, but the most likely place I see a segmentation fault could occur is when your `chromInfo` wasn't initialized correctly with size `chromNum`.

Comment: Do you check for memory allocation errors?  You don't show that...You may have been accidentally hitting a compiler bug in 4.4.6 (so your faulty code runs OK there) that was not in 4.4.4 and was fixed in 4.5.x and above.

Comment: `BIN_SIZE=(2*width)/bins` and `totalBinNum += chromInfo[i].chromSize/BIN_SIZE+1;` I got the feeling there is some sloppy bookkeeping going on here; the +1's are added to correct for the moduli not being zero. The **ALL-CAPS** variable and the signed sizes&counts are not a good sign either. IMnsvHO ...

Comment: I am glad you closed it, it ended up being a very bad question, sorry about that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more precise to do so:

```
binVals = malloc(chromNum*sizeof(float *));
```

But it is not likely that this is the cause of the error, as you can expect that 2 pointers, even if to different types `int*` and `float*`, will have the same size. In short, the source of the error is probably somewhere else in your code.

Some other suggestions:

1. I would suggest removing the other type cast in the other malloc.
2. I would use some temporary variable to store `chromInfo[i].chromSize/BIN_SIZE+1`, so that you do not have to repeat the expression 3 times with very likely cut and past errors.
3. You can compact the `malloc` and the `memset` to zero in one `calloc` call.

Comment: Or even better: `binVals = malloc(chromNum * sizeof *binVals);`

Comment: I still get seg fault, I am thinking it may be in another part of the code... thanks.

Comment: He had `int *` there, not `int`.  It's pretty likely that `float *` and `int *` are the same size.

Comment: @CarlNorum You are right, I have edited my answer

Comment: @Dnaiel: Yes, I confirm: the code could be improved but there is no visible cause for a segmentation fault: it must be triggered somewhere else in your code.